# Should I do bachelor first or pilot training first?

Tags: flight-training, student-pilot, career

I am a student now going to grade 12 residing in Nepal. I am perplexed about should i do my training first  get a job and do bachelor alongside with my job or should I do bachelor first and then training and then get a job.

Answer (score 3):

If you have ready access to university, do the degree first. You won't have time later, and if you get a pilot job in future and lose your medical for whatever reason, you will have an education to fall back on.  In any case, the aviation industry is going to take a number of years to recover from this whole "plague" fiasco, so you shouldn't be in any hurry to get a pilot license.  Thousands of pilots are on furlough and will likely continue to be for quite a while.

Long term, the future is bright, but get a degree first.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, apply to a college which has a flying club open for students. You'll get ground school, flight training, and flying time at a discount and you can pace your progress according to how much free time and money you have.